# Backwards compatible comma list out of <ul>

Tags: css, internet-explorer, cross-browser

I have the following code:

```
.taglist li{
display: inline;
}

.taglist li:after {
content: ", ";
}

.taglist li:last-child:after {
content:"";
}
```

it takes an unordered list of tags and makes it into a nice comma separated list.  Of course in IE7 and earlier there is no space between the list. I'm wondering if anyone has any ideas on how to still use the list technique, but have it not look horrible in older versions of IE.? I tried also adding some margin-right to the li, but it pushed some of the text out of its container and caused it to wrap in very strange ways.

It might not be practical to do this, but it struck me as the most semantic way.

Comment: What's your IE7 share? Mine is "why bother". `:P`

Comment: fun fact, less than 5% of people still use IE7 http://www.w3schools.com/browsers/browsers_explorer.asp

Comment: @Howdy_McGee Maybe the op maintains an IE7 get-the-most-out-of-it website and more than 90% of the visitors are using IE7?

Comment: @Howdy It's still over 10% - [Wikimedia Report](http://stats.wikimedia.org/archive/squid_reports/2011-06/SquidReportClients.htm) - but I expect it to drop steadily in the coming months... (Although other reports show smaller numbers - 5 to 7 percent.)

Comment: IE7 and IE6 together is about 10% perhaps. I don't actually have the stats on the site, but based on the audience I'd guess it'd be higher than average lower end browsers. I was mostly hoping for a fairly simple 'why not just do it' kinda solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Of course in IE7 and earlier there is no space between the list. I'm
>   wondering if anyone has any ideas on how to still use the list
>   technique, but have it not look horrible in older versions of IE.?

If just adding a small gap after each `li` in *only IE7 and lower* is good enough, use this:

```
.taglist li{
    display: inline;
    *padding-right: 6px; /* adjust to taste */
}
```

Comment: I wonder if you could get away with combining this with a `background-image` aligned to the bottom right to simulate a comma on IE?

Answer (score 2):

You can try [ie7-js](http://code.google.com/p/ie7-js/), maybe it helps. If you really care, and ie7-js doesn't work, you can write your own script to fix stuff by inserting text nodes for IE7 via JavaScript.

The best is to keep the HTML good, and try to fix stuff using JavaScript for broken browsers like IE7.

Comment: This is the most sensible answer. ie7-js should work in this instance.